# Ruby & Rails discrepancy re day of week?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

Why is it that in:

Rails Date Monday is the first day of week (0),  where as in Ruby Date it is Sunday?

Rails:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html, DAYS_INTO_WEEKS

Ruby: http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/wday

It would seem confusing that if you create a date in a Rails app that you would get conflicting answers/issues (which is what I struck) when using:

a) my_date.cwday  # would give a "1" for Monday date

b) Date::DAYS_INTO_WEEK[:monday]  # would give a "0" for a monday

Comment: what kind of answer do you expect? both make sense! in some part of the world sunday is expected to be the first day in the week, in others it's monday. so?!

Comment: yes it was kind of generic wasn't it - I'll put some background up, but perhaps best to leave the question as to is there a reason why Rail's Date is following a different approach to Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also method http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/cwday which considers Monday the first day of week. Wiki states that "According to international standard ISO 8601 it is the first day of the work week." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monday) but in many countries Sunday is the first day. Rails seem to follow standard.

Comment: seems strange why Rails for their Date would follow a different approach to ruby